# what is the tcp status after jetty responsing to web browser for a connection

Tags: java, webserver, jetty

as the title said, will jetty close the connection?
netstat cmd report established on my machine.

```
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3003                ::1:41817               ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal HTTP rules apply.

Determine which HTTP version your connection and request was using. (HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0, and with older Jetty versions HTTP/0.9)

Then determine the request persistence mode, based on the version declared in the request portion of the exchange, along with other headers related to that HTTP version in the request and response headers.

From that information you will have the answer on what behavior the connection closure follows for that specific connection.

If this is still confusing, capture the request headers and response headers and update/edit your question to include the headers that were actually used.